# For $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $\epsilon =e^{2\pi i/5}$, determine $|\mathbb Q[\omega +\epsilon]:\mathbb Q|$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

> Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $\epsilon =e^{2\pi i/5}$, then show the following:
> (a) $\omega \notin \mathbb Q[\epsilon]$, and (b) determine $|\mathbb Q[\omega +\epsilon]:\mathbb Q|$.

Clearly $\omega,\epsilon$ are primitive $3$rd root of $1$ and primitive $5$th root of $1$, respectively. Since $Gal(\mathbb Q[\epsilon]/\mathbb Q)=\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z$, if $\omega \in \mathbb Q[\epsilon]$ by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory and cyclicness of $\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z$ we must have $\mathbb Q[\epsilon +\epsilon^{-1}]=\mathbb Q[\omega]$. Note that $(\epsilon +\epsilon^{-1})$ satisfy the irreducible polynomial $x^2+x-1$ over $\mathbb Q$. But $\omega$ is not fixed by the complex conjugation, hence $\omega \notin \mathbb R$. OTOH $(\epsilon + \epsilon^{-1}) \in \mathbb R$. Thus $\mathbb Q[\epsilon +\epsilon^{-1}]\neq \mathbb Q[\omega]$. Therefore $\omega \notin \mathbb Q[\epsilon]$ and part $(a)$ is done. My problem in part $(b)$. We get the tower $\mathbb Q(\omega +\epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\omega,\epsilon)$. Also $\zeta_{15}\in \mathbb Q(\omega,\epsilon)$. I aimed to show that $\mathbb Q(\omega,\epsilon)=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{15})$. May be there are some other direct way to look at the degree, e.g., looking at the number of conjugates of $\omega +\epsilon$. Give me some hint to complete it. Thanks.

Comment: Has the Galois group of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})$ been covered already? Knowing that (and writing everything in terms of $\zeta_{15}$) should help.

Comment: Hmm. Possibly simpler to ignore $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})$. Part (a) tells you that $[\Bbb{Q}(\omega,\epsilon):\Bbb{Q}]=8$. It is clearly Galois, so the Galois group has order $8$. If $\sigma$ is an automorphism, then
$$\sigma(\omega+\epsilon)=\omega^a+\epsilon^b$$ for some $a\in\Bbb{Z}_3^*$ and $b\in\Bbb{Z}_5^*$. By the earlier results all the combos $(a,b)$ occur. If exactly one of $a,b$ is equal to $1$, it is easy to see that the sum is not a fixed point of $\sigma$. If $\omega+\epsilon$ is a fixed point of $\sigma$ it is also a fixed point of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: (cont'd) Unless $\sigma^2$ is the identity this covers more cases. I think the remaining automorphism can be identified as "well-known", and you can conclude :-)

Comment: Gotta go and take advantage of the cooler morning temperature for my orienteering practice. Back in a few hours.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Since $|\mathbb Q(\omega,\epsilon):\mathbb Q|=8$ and $\mathbb Q(\omega + \epsilon)/\mathbb Q$ is separable with $\mathbb Q(\omega+\epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\omega, \epsilon)$, enough to show that $\omega+\epsilon$ has $8$ distinct conjugates, which are of the form shown by you. Now it is clear that $\{\omega+\epsilon^{b}: b \in \mathbb Z_5^{*}\}$ and  $\{\omega^2+\epsilon^{b}: b \in \mathbb Z_5^{*}\}$ both are sets of cardinality $4$. It remains only to show that this two sets do not intersect.

Comment: If $\omega + \epsilon^b=\omega^2 + \epsilon^c $ for some $b,c \in \mathbb Z_5^{*}$, then $\omega^2-\omega=\epsilon^b-\epsilon^c$. How can I conclude from here?

Comment: Many ways. Using $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)\cap \Bbb{Q}(\epsilon)=\Bbb{Q}$ is one. For another: If we denote by $\sigma_{a,b}$ the automorphism that $\omega\mapsto\omega^a$, $\epsilon\mapsto \epsilon^b$, your question asks whether $\omega+\epsilon$ is a fixed point for $\sigma_{2,d}$ for some $d$. We have $\sigma_{2,d}^2=\sigma_{1,d^2}$, so $\omega+\epsilon$ is also a fixed point of $\sigma_{1,d^2}$. Unless $d^2\equiv1\pmod5$ this contradicts the fact that your first set has four distinct numbers. If $d=1$ then we arrive at $\omega^2=\omega$.

Comment: (cont'd)  If $d\equiv-1\pmod5$ then $\sigma_{2,d}$ is the complex conjugation and...

Comment: Thus we show $|\mathbb Q(\omega + \epsilon):\mathbb Q|=8$ by showing $8$ distinct conjugates of $\omega + \epsilon$. Thank you @Jyrki Lahtonen for your patience.

Comment: Well the only quadratic subfield of $\mathbb {Q} (\zeta_5=\epsilon) $ is $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{5})$ which is real and hence $\zeta_3=\omega\notin\mathbb{Q} (\epsilon) $.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to post the collected argument as an answer. That way you get more feedback. Some may be able to point out short cuts etc.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen with your permission I would post an answer along the lines of the comments.

Comment: You may also prove by a simple calculation that both $\omega, \epsilon $ lie in $\mathbb{Q} (\omega+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Containment has to be true, is it really simple? i would like to know.

Comment: Sure!! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment into answer. To reduce typing effort we use $a=\omega, b=\epsilon, c=a+b$.

We have $b^5=1$ and hence $$(c-a) ^5=1$$ The left hand side is of the form $f(c) a+g(c) $ where $f, g$ are polynomials in $c$ with integer coefficients. Why??

Because $a$ is of degree $2$ over $\mathbb {Q} $ and hence all powers of $a$ higher than $1$ can be replaced by a linear combination of the form $pa+q$.

It now follows that $$a=\frac{1-g(c)}{f(c)}\in\mathbb {Q} (c) $$ and then $b=c-a\in\mathbb {Q} (c) $. Hence $\mathbb{Q} (a, b) \subseteq \mathbb {Q} (c) $. And we are done!!

The technique works for any algebraic numbers $a, b$ with $a$ of degree $2$.

Comment: yes, it works. Thanks

Comment: @user371231: just to let you know, if your course demands a proof based on Galois Theory do use the discussion in comments between you and Jyrki.

Answer (score 1):

Let me apply some rather more advanced notions here. If we can find a  prime $p$ such that $[\Bbb Q_p(\omega+\epsilon):\Bbb Q_p]=8$, we will be done.

A natural candidate is $p=5$, since over $\Bbb Q_5$, we know that $\Bbb Q_5(\epsilon)$ is totally ramified, of degree $4$, and $\Bbb Q_5(\omega)$ is unratified quadratic.

To answer the questions, $\omega$ still isn’t in $\Bbb Q_5(\epsilon)$, since the residue field is still $\Bbb F_5$, and (by Hensel) there are no new roots of unity of order prime to $5$. And a quadratic extension of a quartic extension gives an octic extension.

(One could as well have used $p=3$ for this argument.)